Getting the UTC offset for a given chrono::DateTime
I want to write a Rust function that takes a chrono::DateTime, and returns the UTC offset of the timezone of that DateTime. This is my best attempt
fn utc_ofset<Tz: chrono::TimeZone>(dt: chrono::DateTime<Tz>) -> i32 {
    dt.offset().fix().local_minus_utc()
}

I'm confused by FixedOffset::local_minus_utc; what relationship does this have with local time? It seems to do what I want, but the name seems wrong. The documentation only has this to say about the method

Returns the number of seconds to add to convert from UTC to the local time.

As a test, I wrote a small test program to print the offset of a Shanghai timestamp, and it correctly returned UTC +8 (my OS is set to UTC-5)
let dt  = chrono_tz::Asia::Shanghai.from_utc_datetime(&chrono::Utc::now().naive_utc());

let offset = dt.offset().fix().local_minus_utc();
println!("Timezone offset from UTC: {} seconds", offset); // outputs 28800 seconds (8 hours)

I feel like I must be misunderstanding this function, as the result does not seem to depend on the local time, despite what its name and the docs imply. Is this an accurate and generalizable method of getting the UTC offset of the timezone contained in a chrono::DateTime?

I see a number of places in the chrono docs where "local" in the function name doesn't mean "your current system". Many functions like this mean "local" as some provided timezone.

I think I'm getting tripped up because there is Local which implements TimeZone, which does use the system time. Is that to say that the word local is overloaded?

I could agree that it is overloaded, just .minus_utc() would still be clear and avoid the "local" misdirection.

When they say "local" they mean the time zone of the FixedOffset. We can see this from their own tests.
#[test]
fn test_parse_offset() {
    let offset = FixedOffset::from_str("-0500").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(offset.local_minus_utc, -5 * 3600);
    let offset = FixedOffset::from_str("-08:00").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(offset.local_minus_utc, -8 * 3600);
    let offset = FixedOffset::from_str("+06:30").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(offset.local_minus_utc, (6 * 3600) + 1800);
}

Yes, using "local" here is confusing.
